# how to load a "Launch Image" from images.xcassets programmatically not a "Image set"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, launch-screen

Is there a way to load images from the `"Launch Image"` inside the `images.xcassets` programmatically.

This works if the `images.xcassets` is a `"Image set"` but not a `"Launch Image"` anyone know how to get around this?!

```
self.launchImage = UIImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
self.launchImage.image = UIImage(named: "LaunchImage")
self.view.addSubview(self.launchImage)
```

**Launch Image**

[image: Launch Image]

**Image Set**

[image: Image Set]